# Why this return false in JavaScript doesn't cancel the PostBack?

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I have an ASPxButton (DevExpress). On its ClientSideEvents, I need a simple check. If it passes it, it can postback, but if not, it shouldn't postback. My button is;

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="MKREkle" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false" OnClick="Show_MKRPopup" Text="MKR Ekle">
    <ClientSideEvents  Click="OpenMKRPopUp"/>
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

The Javascript function is;

```
function OpenMKRPopUp(s, e) {
    if (IsBitirmeGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex() != -1) {
        MKRPopup.Show();
    } else {
        alert('.....!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

As I checked the answers, everyone said that return false should work but it doesn't. Can you tell me a way?

Comment: `click="OpenMKRPopUp"` -> `click="return OpenMKRPopUp()"`.  And of course, redo the check on the server.

Comment: @mike write it as an answer instead.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, I don't know what the language expects in `ClientSideEvents Click` so I can't put in the usual references to flesh out a full answer.

Comment: it didn't work. gave a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like there is another event listener attached to this button. return or preventDefault() should prevent for submitting any form.

Comment: dxo.Click.AddHandler(return OpenMKRPopUp()); This is from fireBug. I only changed the ClientSideEvents Click to return OpenMKRPopup(). This gave the error.

Comment: I wrote e.preventDefault() but firebug gave e.preventDefault is not a function error. however, it worked. odd

Comment: @Wojciech Bednarski if you could write it as an answer, i ll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is another event listener attached to this button. `return` or `preventDefault()` should prevent for submitting any form.